# get-credential/export-clixml/import-clixml equivalents in nushell

Tags: nushell

I frequently use in powershell this command to store credentials (user and password) in a secure way (password encrypted):

```
get-credential | export-clixml mycredentials.xml
```

and to recover my credentials, I can use:

```
$cred=import-clixml .\mycredentials.xml
```

The password is encrypted and secure, if someone robs my file, it can not be used on another machine and even can not be used by another user on the same machine.

How can I do the same in nushell?
Thanks in advance.

So far, I have not found a similar command or option in your documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no built-in nushell alternative.